# Would Rails' production.log log an HTTP 408 request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, http-status-code-408

I'm running some Rails servers behind unicorn, which is behind nginx.

I can see a handful of POST requests with a status of 408 in nginx's `access.log`.

```
123.45.67.890 - - [17/Mar/2016:01:23:45 +1100] "POST /collections/ABC/items/DEFGH HTTP/1.1" 408 0 "http://catalog.paradisec.org.au/collections/ABC/items/DEFGH/edit" "MY FAVOURITE BROWSER"
```

But I can't see anything from the same time in `unicorn.log` (which doesn't log an awful lot of stuff) or `production.log` (which logs a fair amount of stuff).

Should Rails be logging anything in a HTTP 408 scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

production.log only logs requests which actually reach rails. It seems to me, that a 408 is caused by nginx. This can happen if your unicorn workers are busy. So in this case the request neither reached unicorn nor rails.